# Passing data in yii dependent dropdown

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Am creating a depenednt dropdown in yii1 but i always get an error of htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

This is the controller action code

```
public function actionDistrictList() {
    $id = (int)$_POST['province'];

    $data = Tblsudistricts::model()->findAll('province_id=1');
    Yii::app()->session['districtlist'] = $data; //save created list to session
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), CHtml::encode('[select one]'), true);
    foreach ($data as $value => $name){
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);   
        //echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);

}}
```

What could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Here, In your code

```
foreach ($data as $value => $name){
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
```

`$value` is a index and `$name` is a object, you have to use its parameters 
For eg:

```
Chtml::encode($name->district_name)
```

Instaed of:

```
CHtml::encode($name)
```

Comment: `$value` is also wrong. It should be `array('value' => $name->id)`

Answer (score 0):

[Abhishek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39330404/428543) is correct. However, you also have an issue with `value`. `$value` is the index of the object in the `$data` array not the id.

It looks like you are expecting a `value => name` kind of array for `$data`. If this is the case you should pass `$data` through the [`CHtml::listData`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) function.
You can also avoid the `foreach` loop by using [`CHtml::listOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listOptions-detail)

```
$data = Tblsudistricts::model()->findAll('province_id=1');
$data = CHtml::listData($data, "id", "name");
Yii::app()->session['districtlist'] = $data;
echo CHtml::listOptions(null, $data, array('prompt' => '[select one]'));
```